# Spring Boot @Value annotation in JavaFX project is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx

I followed this tutorial to integrate Spring Boot and JavaFX https://github.com/mvpjava/springboot-javafx-tutorial, and when I'm trying to use @Value annotation in my main class it turns to be null when the JavaFX application starts.

I checked to value annotation with @PostConstruct and in the post construct function, and it gets the desired value. I also tried to define @ConfigurationProperties class, but it also turns to be null when the JavaFX application starts.

Here is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private Parent rootNode;

    @Value("${configurations.applicationName}")
    private String applicationName;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/main.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
        rootNode = fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle(applicationName);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootNode));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        springContext.close();
    }
}
```

As said before, applicationName is null when I get to the start function.

Comment: JavaFX creates an instance of the `Application` subclass itself, which is the instance that `start` (as well as `init` and `stop`) is invoked on. Spring is probably creating its own, separate instance—the one that had `applicationName` injected. I'm not familiar with Spring, however, so I don't know how to work around this problem (if it is the problem).

Comment: Following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPy9mc_O_gU&feature=youtu.be in order to integrate Spring with JavaFX enabled me to get the application name from the properties file.